# Blood Sorcery: the difference between Learned and Improvised Rituals

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

In Blood Sorcery there is a section that explains the difference between learned an improvised rituals. It reads like this:

> Once a practitioner gains experience with her Ritual
>   Discipline, she becomes able to follow the Themes to design
>   variations of rituals she knows, altering the incantations,
>   sacrifices, and formulae of the ritual to achieve related but
>   different—sometimes very different—results. Improvised
>   rituals are slower and more difficult to perform than those
>   the caster has memorized and made part of herself.

Other than this there are no systems associated with these differences. All ritual casting times, factors, even sacrifices are not related to the rituals improvised or learned status. all cruac rituals cost 1 blood per dot, all rituals are extended actions with a roll each turn, all rituals have the same response/result, all rituals use 1 attribute 1 skill and 1 theme, so the same difficulty to perform, so what really is different for systems sake, to know a ritual and improvise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the line you referenced I skimmed the book for improvised and found out these parts...

Blood sorcery page 13:

> Rather than enumerate every possible ritual or miracle,
>   this system breaks the Ritual Disciplines down into
>   Themes that are then combined to produce new effects
>   on the fly—a Sanctified master of the Destruction Theme
>   may attempt any miracle he can think of using that
>   Theme, without the need to buy them separately. There
>   is still a reason to buy rituals with Experience, however.
>   Rituals the practitioner “knows” are easier to cast and
>   more potent than improvised ones.

Learned rituals are easier to cast, and more potent. System is explained later on.

Page 16:

> The dice pool used varies by Discipline and by whether or
>   not the ritual is already known to the ritualist. Improvised
>   rituals always use the same Attribute + Skill combination,
>   adding the character’s dots in the Theme used. Learned
>   rituals, however, use Attributes and Skills according to the
>   following table, added to the Theme in use.

Improved and Learned rituals uses different skill sets. (not an advantage for learned rituals thou)

Page 17:

> **Success:** The ritual succeeds and takes place as
>   described by the player. *Excess successes are lost for
>   improvised rituals*, but they may be assigned to the
>   ritual factor or factors of the player’s choice for learned
>   rituals.

Excess successes are lost for improvised
rituals. (so learned ones can be more potent if you have excess success)

> *Example: An Acolyte ritualist is performing a rite to
>   immunize her coterie from the effects of Vinculum. This is a
>   18 Blood Sorcery
>   Protection •••• effect, so the initial target number of successes
>   is four. Making the effect last until the next sunrise adds three
>   successes to the target, and affecting all three members of the
>   coterie adds another two. The final target number is nine. She
>   rolls Presence + Stealth three times, and gains ten successes.
>   Because the ritualist knows the rite, rather than improvising it
>   from her knowledge of Protection, her player may then spend the
>   extra success. She chooses to increase the duration to a month.*

There are minimal differences between improvised and learned and I cannot see anything proves *Improvised rituals are slower* or *Learned rituals are easier to cast* parts.